# how to i get only URL in json in PHP

Tags: php, json

How to i get data in JSON of Mention format
i want to get data with this formate of json
`{"22":{"quality":"22","type":"video\/mp4","url":"http://`
Please guide me how can i do this.
Thanks in advance

i have already try this code

```
$url = 'http://api.miyulasi.com/youtube/1.0.0/download.php?id=7lCDEYXw3mM';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data;
```

and now responde back is like this

`<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center downbuttonbox"><a href="http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?`

Comment: You are downloading a html page, putting a JSON header will not convert your page. You have to analyse source code of the page and parse it to convert it to json

Comment: @Gwendal dear sir how can i parse and convert i don't know i'm a beginner in PHP please guide me completely thanks

Comment: If you want to get data in json format , You can use json_encode function it converts array to json format. You can check here for more detail this will help you. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php]

Comment: @AnamikaShrivastava dear i already try this but i can't remove other unusable words like this  `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center downbuttonbox">` and video size and etc i want to get only url http://xxxxxx

Comment: I wonder why folks up voted this question.

Comment: Try to downvote to compensate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
<?php

$url = 'http://api.miyulasi.com/youtube/1.0.0/download.php?id=7lCDEYXw3mM';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$links = array();
$expression = "//a[contains(@class, 'btn btn-default btn-sm downbuttonstyle')]";
foreach($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $link) {
    $content = $link->textContent;
    $link = $link->getAttribute('href');
    preg_match("/&mime=([^&]*)&/", $link, $mime);
    preg_match("/&itag=([^&]*)&/", $link, $itag);
    preg_match("/\((.*)\)/", $content, $quality);

    $links[] = array("itag" => $itag[1], "type" => $mime[1], "url" => $link, "quality" => $quality[1]);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($links, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: dear your code is good for me but i can't get full url they give me like this `string 'http://redirector.googlevideo.com/'... (length=734)

Comment: `var_dump` cut string and objects when they are too long, don't worry their is the full URL in the var

Comment: dear can you give in this format `{"22":{"itag":"22","type":"video\/mp4","url":"http://`

Comment: every thing is include in url like itag and video type you need to put from url i can't get this because i don't know more about php

Comment: @forlovepakistan Edited my answer

Comment: great work sir can you remove this `&title=()_Google_IO_101_QA_On_Using_Google_APIs` from url and this [ start and ] end